# How to overcome slow-speeded FileSharing app across WLAN

Tags: c#, file-io, filestream, networkstream, wifi

After a lot more of study and research i was suggested on Stackoverflow to betterly use `FileStream` to open a file on client machine ,send file-name before sending data to server(listening at a pre-defined port),read a fixed-sized data in a buffer chunk-by-chunk ,send it to the remote server.All these operations were tested by me using various buffer-size starting from 10kb to 100MB now.I tested it for small-files and it worked nice.I went with the useful idea of sending 2GB file.it took almost an hour .

Following is the brief coded-idea.

Client-side:

```
   try
        {
            clientSocket.Connect(new IPEndPoint(ipaddrcl, port));

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

        }

        NetworkStream netstream = clientSocket.GetStream();

        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {

            try
            {

                TransmitFileName(netstream, Path.GetFileName(path));
                int data_len = (int)fs.Length;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                int totalbytes = 0;
                while (totalbytes < data_len)
                {
                    var bytesread = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    if (totalbytes == data_len)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    try
                    {
                        netstream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesread);
                        totalbytes += bytesread;

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                        pictureBox.Image = Properties.Resources.Warning;
                        labelProgress.Text = "Error in transmission";

                    }
                }

            }

            finally
            {

                MessageBox.Show("Data transfer completed");
                pictureBox.Image = Properties.Resources.Information;
                labelProgress.Text = "Copying Done";
                fs.Close();
                netstream.Close();
                // change button states
                btnSend.Enabled = true;
                btn_Cancel.Enabled = false;
            }

        }
```

Server-side:

```
      Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(fileloc));
       try
        {
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileloc, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                netStream.CopyTo(fs);
                pictureBox2.Image = Properties.Resources.spinningDisc1;
               // label_server.Text = "Receiving Data";
            }


        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message.ToString());


        }
        finally
        {

            //check the size of file recieved 
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(fileloc);
            long siz = fi.Length;
            MessageBox.Show("Data Recieved: File Size is " + SizeSuffix(siz));
            pictureBox2.Image = null;
           // Thread();

      }
```

In order to enhance speed ,i came across [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36647/How-to-copy-files-in-C-with-a-customizable-progres) and tested `CopyFileEx` for copying folders and trees on local-host and it worked superb.
Now the issue is,Can i use `CopyFileEx` on WLAN and if,yes, how will this ensures me to write a chunk-by-chunk piece of data and still ensures speedy process.

PS.I tried my best to not make it not so-lengthy but efforts are worth to show first before asking.I didn't find any working example for WLAN..if you have please give me a start-up with it.